# How to do word wrap with react-pdf

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-pdf

I have a pdf that is rendering as expected except for an issue where when a very long word is included in the info for the page, instead of wrapping the word onto a newline the word just continues right out the container, off the page, out the door to who knows where.

This is the set-up for one of the containers that's creating this issue. The styles followed by the actual structure.

```
       const styles = StyleSheet.create({
         section: {
            paddingBottom: 20,
            position: 'relative',
         },
         sectionTitle: {
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: 700,
            borderBottom: '2 solid #333333',
            display: 'block',
            marginBottom: 10,
            textTransform: 'uppercase',
            lineHeight: 1.2,
          },
        })
```

Below is the set-up of the section of the page

```
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <StyledText style={styles.sectionTitle}>Description</StyledText>
          <StyledText style={{ width: '80%', fontWeight: 400 }}>
            {data.description}
          </StyledText>
        </View>
```

here data.description is text in the form of:
"looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"
something like this. The container should break the word but no matter how I try to style it the word doesn't respond.
How can I break the word when hits the end of the container?

I've tried using, wordWrap, wordBreak, flex, flexWrap, flexGrow/Shrink and overflowWrap so far. Nothing seems to have any effect

Comment: have you tried any of : word-wrap, word-break, overflow-wrap, ... and which did not work ?

Comment: good point I'll update the post

Comment: oups, after all, it seems not avalaible : https://react-pdf.org/styling#valid-css-properties you might need to split your words before processing ... but still should wrap real words, try using random letters instead a single repeated thousands of time ;)    `gangnabalandehantrebdrtsartreacdetbgangnabalandehantrebdrtsartreacdetbgangnabalandehantrebdrtsartreacdetb` should break.. reactPdf playground shows it works : https://react-pdf.org/repl

Answer (score 7):

Try `style={{ flex: 1 }}` in the component you wish to word break.

Answer (score 1):

I Solved this problem by adding a **maxWidth** property to my column style.

Comment: Oooh!! I was adding it to the `Text` itself. Now it works, ty!

Answer (score 0):

You should cover your tags with `<Text>` and give attribute `display:flex` and `flexDirection:row`.
After these your text will break.

Comment: probably you need to set a width o your text tag

Answer (score 0):

This will split the text into word character and none word character chunks.

```
const WrapText = ({text}: {text?: string}) => (
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
    {text?.match(/\w+|\W+/g)?.map((seg, i) => (
      <Text key={i}>{seg}</Text>
    ))}
  </View>
);
```

Answer (score -2):

In the style of {data.description}, try to use:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction:row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Find more resources here : [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)